# Ubuntu 11.10 wont' upgrade to Firefox 21

Tags: 11.10, apt, firefox

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 on a System76 laptop, and I can't seem to upgrade my firefox to v21. apt-get update, install, and upgrade firefox all return without making any upgrades. Synaptic is the same.

Any help would rock!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to a [supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11.10 has reached its [EOL (End Of Life)](http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife) and you won't get any upgrades for it. You have to [upgrade to another version of Ubuntu.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes#From_11.10_to_12.04_LTS)